# Property of the alternating operator

Tags: multivariable-calculus, permutations, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra, alternating-expression

Let $\Lambda^kV^*$ be the space of alternating k-linear forms on $V^k:=V \times \dots \times V$.

Such that for $\omega \in \Lambda^kV^*$,

$$\omega(v_1, \dots, v_i+v_j,\dots, v_k)=\omega(v_1, \dots, v_i,\dots, v_k)+\omega(v_1, \dots,v_j,\dots, v_k), i,j\in \{1,\dots,k\}$$
$$\omega(v_{\pi(1)}, \dots,v_{\pi(k)})=sgn(\pi)\omega(v_1, \dots, v_k), \pi \in S_k.$$

The alternating operator $Alt^k$ is defined on $\bigotimes^kV^*$, the space of k-linear forms, so $\Lambda^kV^*\subset \bigotimes^kV^*$.
$$Alt^k:\bigotimes^kV^* \longrightarrow \Lambda^kV^* $$
$$\omega(v_1,\dots,v_k) \longmapsto \frac{1}{k!}\sum_\limits{\sigma \in S_k}sgn(\sigma)\omega(v_{\sigma(1)}, \dots,v_{\sigma(k)})$$

So now **I am trying to show** for $\varphi \in \bigotimes^kV^*$ and $\psi \in \bigotimes^lV^*$ that:

$$Alt^{k+l}(\varphi \otimes\psi)=Alt^{k+l}(Alt^k(\varphi)\otimes \psi)$$
with, $\varphi \otimes\psi(v_1,\dots,v_{k+l})=\varphi(v_1,\dots,v_k)\psi(v_{k+1},\dots,v_{k+l})$.

**My attempt**:
So I just tried to simply the right-hand of the equation, doing that we define:
$$\tilde{\varphi}(v_1,\dots,v_k):=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_\limits{\mu \in S_k}sgn(\mu)\varphi(v_{\mu(1)}, \dots,v_{\mu(k)})=Alt^k(\varphi(v_1,\dots,v_k))$$
So that:

\begin{align*}
Alt^{k+l}(Alt^k(\varphi)\otimes \psi)(v_1,\dots,v_{k+l}) =Alt^{k+l}(\tilde{\varphi}\otimes\psi)(v_1,\dots,v_{k+l})=\\
\frac{1}{(k+l)!}\sum_\limits{\sigma \in S_{k+l}}sgn(\sigma)\tilde{\varphi}(v_{\sigma(1)}, \dots,v_{\sigma(k)})\psi(v_{\sigma(k+1)}, \dots,v_{\sigma(k+l)})= \frac{1}{(k+l)!}\sum_\limits{\sigma \in S_{k+l}}sgn(\sigma)\left(\frac{1}{k!}\sum_\limits{\mu \in S_k}sgn(\mu)\varphi(v_{\mu(1)}, \dots,v_{\mu(k)})\right)\psi(v_{\sigma(k+1)}, \dots,v_{\sigma(k+l)})=\dots=\\
\frac{1}{(k+l)!}\sum_\limits{\sigma \in S_{k+l}}sgn(\sigma)\left(\frac{1}{k!}\sum_\limits{\mu \in S_k}\varphi(v_{\sigma(1)}, \dots,v_{\sigma(k)})\right)\psi(v_{\sigma(k+1)}, \dots,v_{\sigma(k+l)})=\\
\frac{1}{(k+l)!}\sum_\limits{\sigma \in S_{k+l}}sgn(\sigma)\frac{k!}{k!}\varphi(v_{\sigma(1)}, \dots,v_{\sigma(k)})\psi(v_{\sigma(k+1)}, \dots,v_{\sigma(k+l)})=Alt^{k+l}(\varphi \otimes\psi)
\end{align*}

**Question**:
I think that is the idea behind it, but I don't really now what to do, to get the equation, after the dots. I thought about using the the fact that $\tilde{\varphi}$ is alternating but, if we look at it with $\sigma \in S_{k+l}$:

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{k!}\sum_\limits{\mu \in S_k}sgn(\mu)\varphi(v_{\mu\circ\sigma(1)}, \dots,v_{\mu\circ\sigma(k)})=\tilde{\varphi}(v_{\sigma(1)}, \dots,v_{\sigma(k)})\neq sgn(\sigma)\tilde{\varphi}(v_{1}, \dots,v_{k})
\end{align*}
,since $\sigma \notin S_k$.

I would love to get a hint or idea (maybe how to approach the problem differently)!

Comment: It is improper to use the same dummy variable in two nested summations

Comment: The left-hand sum has $(k+\ell)!$ terms, while the right-hand sum has $(k+\ell)!\times k!$ terms. Therefore each term must be overcounted $k!$ times on the right-hand side. You re-index the sum to make the overcount clear

Comment: of course the slick thing to do is use the universal property, since the wedge is unique map satisfying whatever properties, just check that both sides satisfy, and so they must be equal. but taming the sum should also work

Comment: @ziggurism we didnt cover the universal property of the wedge. But I am a bit unsure what you mean by re-indexing. Is it useful to rewirte as such:
$ \frac{1}{(k+l)!k!}\sum_\limits{(\sigma ,\mu) \in S_{k+l}\times S_k}sgn(\sigma \circ \mu)\varphi(v_{\mu\circ\sigma(1)}, \dots,v_{\mu\circ\sigma(k)})\psi(v_{\sigma(k+1)}, \dots,v_{\sigma(k+l)})$

Comment: Yeah, something like that. Given a fixed $\mu\in S_k$, then both $\sigma\in S_{k+\ell}$ and $\sigma\mu^{-1}$ are index expressions that range over all of $S_{k+\ell}$ since right multiplication by $\mu^{-1}$ is transitive. So what happens if we use that for the outer index?

Comment: I noticed that you fixed the issue of the reused dummy variable by introducing a second variable $\mu$. that is good, but now it seems that you have used $\mu$ also in the outer sum too, so it is still improper. Also there should be a $\operatorname{sgn}(\mu)$ factor in the inner sum.

Comment: oh wait, this wasn’t actually an issue it was on purpose, since I thought that maybe you could get it to this form. So that the inner sum was independet of the summation, and the sgn would also simplify somehow so that it would simplify into the form I wanted. Hence the dots.

Comment: But you are right, that if you just plug in $\tilde{\varphi}$ that it wouldn’t be the same, sorry for writing it down so confusingly. I added the expression you meant , before the dots.

Comment: so once you cancel $\mu$ i think it will work out